# Spinning, hot and cold reserve

Tags: electrical-engineering

I am facing a challenge in understanding the actual meaning of spinning reserve, hot reserve as well as cold reserve as used in power generation.
Anyone to help clarify for me please.

Comment: Check out Dinorwig.

Answer (score 0):

**Spinning reserve** is generating capacity that is working and connected to the grid, but operating below its capacity, such as a partially loaded gas turbine.  As demand is needed in the grid, the turbine will increase its load to provide the required demand.  A system with no spinning capacity cannot meet additional demand, and system voltage will drop in reaction to increased demand.

**Hot capacity** is generating capacity that is ready to be connected to the grid without plan warmup, such as a coal plant at normal operating temperature and pressure but not actively making power. We can quickly connect this plant to the grid and ramp up power production.

**Cold capacity** is generating capacity that has to be started up to meet demand.  This would be a shut down gas turbine or even a coal plant that has to be started up  from cold to meet demand on the grid.  This capacity might be hours from use.